# Move JS file generated by typescript (saved during runtime) via gulp

Tags: typescript, gulp, asp.net-core, gulp-watch

In the new ASP.NET 5 project, there is a folder called `wwwroot` that usually contains the js, css and other files accessible by web requests.

My typescript files are located outside this folder. Whenever I save the ts files, I want the generated js files to be transferred to the wwwroot folder.
This can be easily done during build time.

However, I want this to happen also whenever I change and save the ts files during runtime.

I use [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) as seen below but it does not work.

```
gulp.task('watch:ts', function () {
      gulp.watch('Contents/Scripts/**/*.ts', ['min:site:js']);
     });
```

`min:site:js` is my task that moves the js files to wwwroot

```
gulp.task('min:site:js', function () {
return gulp
  .src('Contents/Scripts/**/*.js', { relative: true })
  .pipe(newer('wwwroot/js/'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/js/'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/js/'));
});
```

Comment: We will need to see the implementation of your min:site:js task.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that gulp.dst is finishing the stream.
 Plus, you try to write two times (using gulp.dest twice). In my opinion, that doesnt make any sense.

Instead, try this:

```
gulp.task('min:site:js', function () {
return gulp
  .src('Contents/Scripts/**/*.js', { relative: true })
  .pipe(newer('wwwroot/js/'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/js/'));
});
```